# WebFragmentの呼び出しについて

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview

WebFragment呼び出し方法について終えて下さい。

WebViewActivityクラスのソース↓

```
〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜
    private class WebViewFragment():
            WebFragment(),
            AdEventHandlerDelegate,
            FavorEventHandlerDelegate,
            ShareEventHandlerDelegate,
            NewPageEventHandlerDelegate,
            LoginPageEventHandlerDelegate,
            LogoutPageEventHandlerDelegate
    {
〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜
 override fun openUriInNewPage(uri: Uri) {

            openUriInNewWebViewActivity(uri)

        }

 override fun showLoginPage() {

            val uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.jp/")
            openUriInNewPage(uri)

        }
```

openUriInNewWebViewActivity(uri)はWebFragmentクラスのメソッドを呼び出しているようですが、認識正しいでしょうか？↓uriでhttps://www.google.co.jp/を渡しているからgoogleのページが開く？

WebFragmentクラスのソース

```
 public open class WebFragment():
            Fragment(),
            UriLoadable
    {
    
        protected object KeyName {
    
            val Uri = "Uri"
    
        }
// open uri externally
protected open fun openUri(uri: Uri) {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
    startActivity(intent)

}

protected open fun openUriInNewWebViewActivity(uri: Uri) {

    if (!Constants.isGoogleDomain(uri)) {

        openUri(uri)

    } else {

        val intent = Intent(getActivity(), javaClass<WebViewActivity>())
        intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.default_webview_activity_uri), uri.toString())

        startActivity(intent)

    }

}

}
```

Fragmentについて中々理解が出来ないのですが、この場合ですとWebViewで無いのは何故でしょうか？（ソースがこれだけだと分かりにくいと思いますが定番の使い方で予想されることとか。）